# Accessibility (TalkBack) : How to make a particular view focussed automatically, just after the complete fragment loads?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, fragment, focus, accessibility

- When I click on a certain option, while the talkback feature is on, the selection  of the view remains the same in the next fragment also.
- Either the selection or focus the view in the first fragment should be removed or the another view in the next fragment should be focussed.
- Currently I am using the following code :

  ```
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
  view.SendAccessibilityEvent(Android.Views.Accessibility.EventTypes.ViewFocused);
  ```
- But is this a good practice because I am adding delay in the system.

Comment: can you try making the view in question request focus when layout is completely inflated in fragment, that's how I would try

Comment: I tried request focus too, but that too is not working. The only working code is as mentioned above. But I am asking for a better alternative because it is adding delay in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform accessibility action with focus on view in onActivityCreated method like below

```
view.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if your fragment/activity have indivual view:

```
<view_id>.requestFocus()
<view_id>.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
```

if you have RecyclerView and you want to focus at the topmost item :

```
 <recyclerView_id>.post {
            val child = this.getChildAt(0)
            child?.let {
                it.requestFocus()
                it.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
            }
        }
```